# Creating an infinate loop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am looking at creating a program in vb.net that loops constantly checking a .txt file for URL's. The application will then use a HTTP Web Request to call each URL (a bit like cron jobs)

but i would like this to constantly loop round and round. would this be a bad idea to have it going constantly, currently i am using a timer which runs every 10 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) which was made for this purpose. You will be notified if the file changes in [`OnChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onchanged.aspx).

You can use a windows service, here's a tutorial: [How to implement a simple filewatcher Windows service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18521/How-to-implement-a-simple-filewatcher-Windows-serv) (in C# but you can use a converter like [this](http://converter.telerik.com/)).

Using a windows service has advantages:

- it's running always if the service runs, so basically it's your "infinite loop"
- You can control the user and the rights which starts the process
- a policy on failure can be defined (try to restart n times run a specific program if fails)

Comment: i dont want it to run when the file is changed/modified, just simply to run ALL the time

Comment: @Charles: yes, you can use a windows service(as mentioned) but to avoid that you have to open and read the file constantly you can use the `FileSystemWatcher` which is active only after the file was modified.

Comment: your saying about the file being modified?

Comment: @Charles: yes, if I understood correctly you want to go to the URL's in the file but only after the file was changed. If you want to do that constantly keep your timer approach but use a windows-service anyway.